# spotify stream history - weird values

Tags: spotify

so I've recently gotten my Spotify data, but the documentation is a little lacking on some points, so I wanted to see if anyone here maybe has some more insight.

Firstly, the 'skipped' value can be either be False, True or null. Does anyone know how a null value could be interpreted as (I have a lot of null values, so it kinda bothers me).

[image: three quarters of the skipped values are null values]

Secondly, it feels like some 'ms_played' values don't add up. There are some songs that got played way longer than its song length, does that mean I restarted the songs over and over again without other songs in between, or how should I interpret this?

If anyone knows more about the Spotify data, please let me know!

Answer (score 0):

I'm playing around with the Streaming History aswell and from the Data from myself and my Friends i recon `NULL` Values are not uncommon.
I got many entries with `NULL` values as `track_name` or `artist_name`, I guess those tracks have been deleted.
Looking into the `skipped` fields, Boolean values start to appear from 2022-10-15 on, so I think this feature wasn't implemented before, thus the values are filled with `NULL`. (Although I see a handful exceptions)

Comment: i have null values in 'skipped' going back to 2016 so i dont think that thats the case. but the other ones might actually be deleted songs/artists like you said.